# Combine react-easy-crop with react-uploady

Tags: javascript, reactjs, crop

I am trying to combine [react-easy-crop.js](https://ricardo-ch.github.io/react-easy-crop/) with [react-uploady.js](https://react-uploady.netlify.app/) but do not succeed. There is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-uploady-crop-and-upload-uyl4e?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) in which react-uploady is combined with react-image-crop which I am trying to adapt using react-easy-cropper. After selecting a picture to be shown in the cropper and then pressing 'UPLOAD CROPPED' I run into an error:

```
TypeError
Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLCanvasElement or HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas or SVGImageElement or VideoFrame)'.
```

and do not know how to proceed.

The codesandbox showing this behavior is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-easy-crop-with-uploady-crop-and-upload-fork-93p5u?file=/src/App.js:2557-2569).

How can I avoid this error? How should react-easy-crop be implemented with react-uploady?

Comment: Your sandbox gives an error at startup...

Comment: not sure which error either the question or the comment refer to. Im able to use the original (which I wrote) just fine from loading the sandbox to uploading a cropped file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the issue is with the original sandbox or with the adaptation to *react-easy-crop* but I was able to easily adapt it to the desired library (despite not liking its UI very much, but to each his own, I guess)

In any case, here's a working sandbox with *react-easy-crop*: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-uploady-crop-and-upload-with-react-easy-crop-5g7vw

Including here the preview item that I updated:

```js
const ItemPreviewWithCrop = withRequestPreSendUpdate((props) => {
  const {
    id,
    url,
    isFallback,
    type,
    updateRequest,
    requestData,
    previewMethods
  } = props;
  const [uploadState, setUploadState] = useState(UPLOAD_STATES.NONE);
  const [croppedImg, setCroppedImg] = useState(null);

  //data for react-easy-crop
  const [crop, setCrop] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(1);
  const [croppedAreaPixels, setCroppedAreaPixels] = useState(null);

  const onCropComplete = useCallback((croppedArea, croppedAreaPixels) => 
    setCroppedAreaPixels(croppedAreaPixels),
 []);

  const isFinished = uploadState === UPLOAD_STATES.FINISHED;

  useItemProgressListener(() => setUploadState(UPLOAD_STATES.UPLOADING), id);
  useItemFinalizeListener(() => setUploadState(UPLOAD_STATES.FINISHED), id);

  const onUploadCrop = useCallback(async () => {
    if (updateRequest && croppedAreaPixels) {
      const [croppedBlob, croppedUri] = await getCroppedImg(
        url,
        croppedAreaPixels
      );

      requestData.items[0].file = croppedBlob;

      updateRequest({ items: requestData.items });
      setCroppedImg(croppedUri);
    }
  }, [url, requestData, updateRequest, croppedAreaPixels]);

  const onUploadCancel = useCallback(() => {
    updateRequest(false);
    if (previewMethods.current?.clear) {
      previewMethods.current.clear();
    }
  }, [updateRequest, previewMethods]);

  return isFallback || type !== PREVIEW_TYPES.IMAGE ? (
    <PreviewImage src={url} alt="fallback img" />
  ) : (
    <>
      {requestData && uploadState === UPLOAD_STATES.NONE ? (
        <div className="crop-view">
          <div className="crop-container">
            <Cropper
              image={url}
              crop={crop}
              zoom={zoom}
              aspect={4 / 3}
              onCropChange={setCrop}
              onCropComplete={onCropComplete}
              onZoomChange={setZoom}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="controls">
            <input
              type="range"
              value={zoom}
              min={1}
              max={3}
              step={0.1}
              aria-labelledby="Zoom"
              onChange={(e) => {
                setZoom(e.target.value);
              }}
              className="zoom-range"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <PreviewImage src={croppedImg || url} alt="img to upload" />
      )}
      <PreviewButtons
        finished={isFinished}
        crop={crop}
        updateRequest={updateRequest}
        onUploadCancel={onUploadCancel}
        onUploadCrop={onUploadCrop}
      />
      <p>{isFinished ? "FINISHED" : ""}</p>
    </>
  );
});
```

The change was pretty seamless, just a matter of using the different cropper, and wrapping it with a bit different CSS due to the way it looks&behaves. I took the image cropping code from their example over at: https://codesandbox.io/s/q8q1mnr01w?file=/src/cropImage.js